# Select in M-N relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
product{
    id
    name
}
product_keyword{
    prod_id
    keyword_id
}
keyword{
    id
    keyword
}
```

Where a given product can have multiple keywords and a keyword can belong to multiple products.
Now I would like to, given a certain product, select all the "keyword-related" products. That is, if "prod" have keywords "key1" and "key2" I would like to select all products that have either "key1" or "key2" as keywords.

Comment: You need 2 `INNER JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with joins:

```
select distinct p1.id, p1.name
from product p1
inner join product_keyword pk1 on pk1.prod_id = p1.id
inner join product_keyword pk2 on pk2.keyword_id = pk1.keyword_id
inner join product p2 on p2.id = pk2.prod_id
where p2.name = ?
```

The question mark represents the name of the product whose associated products you want to bring.